# Web scrape all PDF files from a html page

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've tried downloading PDF files from a html page with no success, below is what I have managed to do so far:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

p.html <- htmlParse("http://kenyalaw.org/caselaw/cases/search/")
p.links  <- xpathSApply(p.html, path="//a", xmlGetAttr, "href")
p.urls  <- p.links[grep("*.pdf", p.links)]
```

I'm not able to list all the links with PDF. What could be the problem?

Comment: There are no instance of the string "pdf" at that page.

Comment: That's the search page with an empty search box and no results. There are no PDFs.

Comment: You're in a bit of an ethical/legal conundrum on this site. Their [`robots.txt`](http://kenyalaw.org/robots.txt) allows access to that path prefix (note that they also _disallow_ access to the old `CaseSearch` path prefix), say `civil case 571 of 2015 `, the results show up dynamically b/c Google Site Search searches Google & issues an XHR request for the results ^ dynamically builds the list. Google expressly forbids scraping of search results, including site-search. You shld get permission before continuing esp since that site is a legal site & they know how to use  & Google is in the mix.

Comment: @hrbrmstr material has a CC license

Comment: The _access to Google_ does not. Content license is different from a service owner prohibiting scraping and Google prohibits it without express permission and that site — for the older path — definitely does, too.